# cannot find the correct syntax for this

Tags: button, xpath, click, row

I have a row in the table:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Cape Town')]
```

and the delete graphic:

```
//*[contains(@id, 'DeleteLinkButton')]
```

in the table.

How do I click on `//*[contains(@id, 'DeleteLinkButton')]` of row `//*[contains(text(), 'Cape Town')]`?

Comment: If you provide a snippet of the html code it'll be easier to understand what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a node with XPath in relation to another node then in most cases you don't want to use an absolute path starting with `/` or even `//`,  instead you would use a relative path like `.//*[contains(@id, 'DeleteLinkButton')]` as that would find descendants of the context node where the `id` attribute value contains `DeleteLinkButton`.

So with Javascript in the browser you would have e.g.

```
var myRow = ...;
```

and then you could call

```
myRow.ownerDocument.evaluate('.//*[contains(@id, 'DeleteLinkButton')]', myRow, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();
```